# Blocking nature of msgrcv

Tags: c, message-queue

I sent message from one process to another using message queue. The process receiving messages prints output only after all calls to `msgrcv` function are done. What I was expecting is that it will print data as it receives a message but it prints data only after receiving all messages.

I have tried changing permissions. Ihave used `0666 | IPC_NOWAIT, 0666 | IPC_NOWAIT | IPC_CREAT`.

**server.c**

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/ipc.h>
#include <sys/msg.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <string.h>

struct mesg_buffer {
  long mtype;
  char mtext[100];
};

int main(void){
  struct mesg_buffer message;
  int sq_msgid, uq_msgid;
  int num_users = 0;
  sq_msgid = msgget(ftok("server_queue",1), 0666 | IPC_CREAT);
  uq_msgid = msgget(ftok("user_queue",1), 0666 | IPC_CREAT);
  for(int i=0;i<2;i++){
    printf("%ld",msgrcv(sq_msgid, &message, sizeof(message), 1, 0));
  }
}
```

**client.c**

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/ipc.h>
#include <sys/msg.h>
#include <pthread.h> 
#include <semaphore.h>
#include <signal.h>
#include <string.h>

struct mesg_buffer {
  long mtype;
  char mtext[100];
};

int main(void){
  struct mesg_buffer message;
  int sq_msgid, uq_msgid;
  sq_msgid = msgget(ftok("server_queue",1), 0666 | IPC_CREAT);
  strcpy(message.mtext, "join");
  message.mtype = 1;
  int r = msgsnd(sq_msgid, &message, sizeof(message), 0);
  printf("%d", r);
}
```

Comment: Try adding newlines to your `printf()` calls or use `fflush(stdout)` after them.

Comment: Figured it would. Nothing to do with `msgrcv()`, everything to do with stdio buffering.

Comment: why do we need to flush output here?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1716296/why-does-printf-not-flush-after-the-call-unless-a-newline-is-in-the-format-strin Also, you're not checking the return value from `ftok()`.  Using `ftok()` to get a message queue ID is pretty error-prone.  The file must exist, there's no guarantee that if the file is deleted and recreated you wind up with the same number, and there's no guarantee that even if `ftok()` works that you'll get a value back that uniquely identifies a message queue with - `ftok()` can return a value that will refer to a queue that's already in use by someone/something else.

Comment: @s.singh you need to flush (or use '\n' in print) because printf (and other functions of stdio) make some kind of optimization by waiting one of those 2 triggers before displaying anything. It then reduces the amount of calls to write () which hides a syscall and fastens your program ;)

Answer (score 0):

As I get response in comments, whenever I need to show output to console, 
 I just need to use `fflush(stdout)`.